# Generate blurhash while uploading image to server using Next js

Tags: reactjs, image, next.js

Next Js has blurhash in the hood by default for local images. but when it comes to url images we need to pass a `blurDataURL` to next image. and to generate this image we must setup the generator to backend server to handle this action.

for my upload process i'm using react Dropzone and firebase for the database. all this is done in frontend. and I haven't found any article or tutorial to generate blurhash myself when i'm uploading or converting the fetched image url to blurhash.

```
const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const images = useSelector(selectImages);
  const [files, setFiles] = useState(images == [] ? [] : images);

const {getRootProps, getInputProps} = useDropzone({
onDrop: (acceptedFiles) => {
     acceptedFiles.map((file, index) => {
        const reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = async function (e) {
          const options = {
            maxSizeMB: 5,
            maxWidthOrHeight: 1920,
            useWebWorker: true,
          };
          const compressedFile = await imageCompression(file, options);

          const tot = parseInt(acceptedFiles.length) + parseInt(files.length);
          if (tot > 9) {
            alert("select maximum of 9 images");
          } else if (parseInt(acceptedFiles.length) > 9) {
            alert("maximum images to be selected is 9");
          } else if (parseInt(files.length) < 9) {
            setFiles((prevState) => [
              ...prevState,
              {
                id: index,
                src: URL.createObjectURL(compressedFile),
                name: file.name,
              },
            ]);

            files.map((filename) => {
              acceptedFiles.forEach((newFile) => {
                if (newFile.name == filename.name) {
                  alert("a duplicate image is detected");

                  setFiles(
                    files,
                    files.filter((val) => val !== newFile)
                  );
                }
              });
            });
          } else {
            alert("something went wrong");
          }
        };
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        return file;
      });
    },
})
```

so is there a way to generate blurhash either while uploading or using url images?

Comment: I created [blurhash-from-url](https://www.npmjs.com/package/blurhash-from-url) it also has [CLI](https://www.npmjs.com/package/blurhash-cli) and offline support too

Comment: @MCNaveen do i convert it to blurdata for next js? or does it handle it on it self

Comment: @MCNaveen i used it and it threw an error `Module parse failed: Unexpected character '�' (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders`